# Creating a function which returns a table where different columns come from different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to write a function in `Postgresql` with 2 parameters which returns a table. This table will have two columns (`column1` and `column2`), and for each of these columns I would need to get information from a column coming from another table (`table1` or `table2`) according to the parameters of the function (`param1` and `param2`). Something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION trial(param1 VARCHAR(50), param2 VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS TABLE (
    column1 VARCHAR(50),
    column2 VARCHAR(50)

AS $$
    BEGIN 
    RETURN QUERY 
        SELECT c1 as column1 FROM table1 WHERE column1 = param1;
        SELECT c2 as column2 FROM table2 WHERE column2 = param2;
    END;    
$$LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

My problem is that if I run this function with the two parameters, for example

```
SELECT trial('car', 'house');
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM trial('car', 'house');
```

I get an error like this:

```
ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type
DETAIL:  Number of returned columns (1) does not match expected column count (2).
```

I can imagine that the problem is the way I do the QUERY, but I can't find the proper manner to do it. How can I query from 2 tables to fill my column1 and column2, if the two tables from which I want to query have nothing in common and I can't do a JOIN?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Sergio

Answer (score 1):

Your code only returns the result of a the first query, the second query is no longer part of the `return query`.

You need to write **one** query with one scalar sub-select for each column you want to return

```
select (SELECT c1 as column1 FROM table1 WHERE column1 = param1), 
       (SELECT c2 as column2 FROM table2 WHERE column2 = param2);
```

You also don't need PL/pgSQL for this. A `language sql`function will do just fine and is a bit more efficient:

```
CREATE FUNCTION trial(param1 VARCHAR(50), param2 VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS TABLE (
    column1 VARCHAR(50),
    column2 VARCHAR(50)

AS $$
  select (SELECT c1 as column1 FROM table1 WHERE column1 = param1), 
         (SELECT c2 as column2 FROM table2 WHERE column2 = param2);
$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much for your kind help.